# Как соединить два многомерных массива?

Tags: php, массивы, веб-программирование

Есть два массива:

- `$products`
- `$attributes`

В массивах содержится одинаковое количество элементов. Их может быть до 500 000 элементов.

Необходимо их объединить в один массив, чтобы потом можно было работать с ним. У них есть связующий элемент: `product_id`

**Массив продуктов**

```
$products = array(
   [0] = array(
       [product_id] => 102966
       [price] => 11
   )
   [1] = array(
       [product_id] => 102967
       [price] => 22
   )
)
```

**Массив атрибутов**

```
$attributes= array(
   [0] = array(
       [product_id] => 102966
       [attr_name] => Диагональ;Длительность ролика
       [attr_value] => 2";1 мин, 2 мин, 3 мин, 5 мин
   )
   [1] = array(
       [product_id] => 102967
       [attr_name] => Выходы;Диагональ;Дополнительная информация
       [attr_value] => HDMI;2.7";рабочие диапазоны
   )
)
```

Подскажите, как их объединить с учетом, чтобы это работало не слишком долго и не съело всю память

**Есть решение:**
Но  ест много ресурсов...

```
$products = array_map(function($product) use ( $attributes ) {
  $attribute = array_filter($attributes, function($attribute) use ( $product ) {
    return $attribute['product_id'] === $product['product_id'];
  });

  return array_merge($attribute ? current($attribute) : [], $product);
}, $products);

print_r($products);
```

Comment: Вот именно этот ответ я хотел дать вам в итоге, что значит «ест много ресурсов»? Очистите память от ненужных массивов явно на крайняк.

Comment: Массивы берутся из БД? Если так, то почему не сделать `join` этих таблиц и не получить на выходе 1 массив?

Comment: Пытался так делать. Возникла одна проблема. Когда я использовал join для таблицы, я юзал concat_group, чтобы собрать в одну строку атрибуты. Все работало. Но мне еще нужно было собрать так же само с другой таблицы изображения. И получилось так, что они(значения атрибутов) начали дублироваться. Так само дублировались и изображения. То есть, проблема была в нескольких join и concat_group.
Там не сложный запрос, но победить его не смог. Использовал DISTINCT, но он удалял некоторые значения атрибутов(есть похожие)

Comment: покажите схемы таблиц

Answer (score 0):

Для каких целей это делается? Запрос к данному массиву будет у каждого юзера на сайте постоянно? Например при открытии корзины или страницы товаров?

Если да, то лучше создать отдельный файл, который выполняет ваш "ресурсоемкий код" и далее записывает построчный результат (соедененныого массива) в некую новую таблицу в базе. Установить этот файл в crontab и пускайте он запускается раз в минуту, раз в час и т.д. Время можете установить исходя из вероятности обновления $products и $attributes.

Как понимаем, речь об интернет магазине и вряд ли прям каждую минуту будут добавляться товары или новые атрибуты.

Ну а для самого пользователя выборка будет с конкретной таблице (а лучше к кешу) с уже готовым общим массивом.